# An ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, csv, indexoutofboundsexception

I am taking one csv comparing each line with every line of another csv to find matches.
I then need to add some elements from the second csv with some from the first and write it to a new file. 
It works for the first lines of the csv then gets the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.
I understand how arrays work and I've checked my csv and as far as I can see I'm not going out of bounds.

The first csv has 8 fields and  contains all the customer info. The second has 15 fields and holds sales info on customers. the first 2 fields `[0]` and `[1]` are the same in both csv's if there is a record of sales.

If anyone could have a quick look I may be missing something stupid.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
        at excel.parse.ExcelParse.main(ExcelParse.java:61)

package excel.parse;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


public class ExcelParse {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String csvFile2 = "\\\\SBS2011\\RedirectedFolders\\Josh.Hickinbotham\\My Documents\\Customer_Sales_Trends_Summary_by_Sales_Order_114641390.csv";
    String csvFile1 = "\\\\SBS2011\\RedirectedFolders\\Josh.Hickinbotham\\My Documents\\All_Customers_Listing_for_Rep_114337469.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    BufferedReader br2 = null;
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    String line = "";
    String line2 = "";
    String csvSplitBy = ",";
    Boolean match = false;

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile1));
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("\\\\SBS2011\\RedirectedFolders\\Josh.Hickinbotham\\My Documents\\newcsv.txt"));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // use comma as separator
            String[] customer = line.split(csvSplitBy);
            System.out.println(customer[1]);
            br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile2));
            while ((line2 = br2.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] file2 = line2.split(csvSplitBy);

                if (customer[1].equals(file2[1])) {
                    match = true;                        
                    bw.write(customer[0] + "," + customer[1] + "," + customer[2] + "," + customer[3] + "," + customer[4] + ","
                        + customer[5] + "," + customer[6] + "," + customer[7] + ","+ file2[2] +","+ file2[3] + "," + file2[4] + "," + file2[5] + ","
                        + file2[6] + "," + file2[7] + "," + file2[8] + "," + file2[9] + "," + file2[10] + "," + file2[11] + "," + file2[12] + ","
                        + file2[13] + "," + file2[14]+"\r\n");
                    System.out.println(":::MATCH " +customer[1]+" : "+file2[1]+" :::");
                } else {
                    match = false;
                }
            }
            if (match == false) {
                bw.write(customer[0] + "," + customer[1] + "," + customer[2] + "," + customer[3] + "," + customer[4] + ","
                    + customer[5] + "," + customer[6] + "," + customer[7] + "," + "," + "," + "," + "," + "," + "," + "," + "," + "," + ","
                    + "," + ","+"\r\n");
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (br2 != null) {
            try {
                br2.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (bw != null) {
            try {
                bw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }          
    }
    System.out.println("Done");
}
}
```

Comment: You haven't told us where the exception is, nor what the content of the file is - in particular the broken line. What diagnostics have you performed to work out where the problem is?

Comment: With code like that, the least you could do is give us an actual error message.

Comment: Im sorry it was supposed to be a quick program never to be used again. The error is on line if (match == false) {              bw.write(customer[0] .....    The annoying thing is it runs through some of the data then fails but all the data is formatted the same.

Comment: can you post the content of the file please?

Comment: Error code is :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at excel.parse.ExcelParse.main(ExcelParse.java:61)
Java Result: 1

Comment: I cant as it contains customer data. but it is in csv from an excel spreadsheet. [CompanyCode][Name][Address](6 address fields) so 8 in total. The second file is [CompanyCode][Name][Jan][Feb][March] so on then[total] at the end 15 fields in total. There is no difference in the layout of the files to make a difference so it has to be in my code somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try displaying what `customer` is before it goes into the `if match == false`. 
May help to see what exactly you are dealing with. :)

Answer (score 0):

What about a simple check on the bounds of the result of "split" ? if you dump your line at the point where the bounds are not OK, you will see the faulty input data....

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your file containing the csv. Maybe debug it and stop at the line where you get the exception to check what data `customer` contains.

But what I wanted to note:
I'm not sure your program is doing what it is supposed to do. When it finds a match it will print it out, but then keep going in the inner `while` loop and so at the end `match` will be false again and you print out the non-match.
So I think you want to put a `break`:

```
if (customer[1].equals(file2[1])) {
     match = true;                        
     bw.write(customer[0] + "," + customer[1] + "," + customer[2] + "," + customer[3] + "," + customer[4] + ","
                    + customer[5] + "," + customer[6] + "," + customer[7] + ","+ file2[2] +","+ file2[3] + "," + file2[4] + "," + file2[5] + ","
                    + file2[6] + "," + file2[7] + "," + file2[8] + "," + file2[9] + "," + file2[10] + "," + file2[11] + "," + file2[12] + ","
                    + file2[13] + "," + file2[14]+"\r\n");
    break;
}
```